# How to add two forums in one rails app using thredded gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm new to Rails, and I built a forum using thredded gem and Ruby on Rails 7,
I watched this tutorial https://youtu.be/at1K99ACM4g
I have a previous forum, and I want to add another forum, is that even possible?

I really didn't try any methods, because I didn't find any.

in the tutorial, I added this line of code to the routes.rb

```rb
#config\routes.rb
mount Thredded::Engine => '/forum'
```

is there a way that I can do something like change the routes to make two different forums, I tried to put another one to the routes, didn't work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with that gem. Have you checked the documentation to see if it is already possible to do what you want?
The best way forward for you is going to be to write your own forum.

The issue you have is in the fact that maybe you could mount the Thredded engine in multiple locations giving you different urls for each forum they will still use the same database and tables so the information will just be shared between the two forums.

There is no way to achieve this in an application but it could be solved by writing your own engines for each forum and overriding the migrations to supply different table names and using the deface gem to reopen models and supply different table names etc..., this could also potentially be done by editing the original gem to supply an initializer that allows maybe a namespace for the forum that then gets prepended to the various model and table names and then issue a pull request to the gem repository for those changes to be included.

Being new to rails I suspect this is a little too much to be starting out with.

Another option might be to fork the engines themselves and make suitable adjustments to the table names but that way you loose any updates made to the master branch

Did you check the gem to see if it is possible to do this already?

So you are left with writing multiple websites hosted on multiple servers with an overriding controlling website that links the forums together or write your own forum, it's simple enough to do

Comment: Ok I will try to change something in the gem, thanks!